# Cannot truffle migrate project

Tags: solidity, truffle

Not having issues compiling project. When I `truffle migrate` I receive this error:

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  Migrations: 0x60fff93824e024bc3ae45e548138a01e1faa125f
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying ConvertLib...
  ConvertLib: 0x50b2d957e2bb477053b362e6d179297c037f53ff
  Linking ConvertLib to MetaCoin
  Deploying MetaCoin...
  MetaCoin: 0xc5bf0d8abb18763eb3be5a5ff5dbe976fb3acff8
  Deploying Node...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful         transactions manually.
Error: Node contains unresolved libraries. You must deploy and link the following libraries before you can deploy a new version of Node: ConvertLib
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/contract.js:345:17
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Here is my `Node` contract (`MetaCoin` is `Ownable`):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
import "./Relay.sol";
import "./MetaCoin.sol";

contract Node is MetaCoin {

uint public fee;
address public owner;
address[] public publicRelays;

  function Node() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    fee = 10;
  }

  function createRelay () returns (address){
    address relay = new Relay();
    publicRelays.push(relay);
    return relay;
  }
}
```

Not sure what the issue is. Any help in the right direction would be great. Using `Truffle v3.2.1`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you import MetaCoin.sol in Node.sol, and the `Node` contract inherits from `MetaCoin`, that means Node.sol includes all the MetaCoin.sol code. This means you need to also link `ConvertLib` to `Node`.

The solution is to change this line in your migration:

`deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin)`

To this:

`deployer.link(ConvertLib, [MetaCoin, Node])`

So, in English: "Link Convertlib to MetaCoin and Node."